# Queue Input binding string expressions not resolving in isolated Azure functions

Tags: azure-functions

We are migrating from in-proc Azure functions to isolated (out-of-proc) Azure functions. In in-proc functions we were reading queue input bindings from `appsettings` using a string expressions like

```
public async Task Run(\[QueueTrigger("%Functions:OCR:QueueName%", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")\] string myQueueItem)
```

`%Functions:OCR:QueueName%` is resolved from `appsettings` key:

```
{
    "Functions": {
        "ocr": {
            "QueueName": "ocr-dev",
            "Disabled": false
        }
    }
}
```

This works correctly in in-proc, but doesn't works in isolated functions.

Do isolated functions support resolving string expressions from configuration files?

I tried to write custom implementation of `INameResolver` but that also doesn't work. Get exception that Azure runtime is not able to parse the string

Comment: Give a try by changing the colons to double Underscores (__) like `%Functions__OCR__QueueName%`

Comment: @HariKrishna I tried your suggestion, but still it fails with the below error

` Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: '%Functions__OCR__QueueName%' does not resolve to a value.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user @*GauravMantri* has been raised the similar issue recently in the GitHub Official Forum of the Azure Functions dotnet worker.

Reference - [How to use Azure App Config Service with Azure Functions for binding input parameters · Issue #1437 · Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker (github.com)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/1437)

> worker configuration sources are not currently supported by extensions/bindings, as that configuration must be available at the app/platform level (platform components depend on that configuration).

The current solution is to use the Azure [App Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-configuration-references) for the Nested App Configuration Object in both the local environment and Azure Portal Function App.